# How to handle MetaMask disconnecting from dapp?

Tags: metamask, javascript

How do you detect when a MetaMask user disconnects their wallet from your dapp? I see there is a [`disconnect event`](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html#events), but this is a for disconnecting from RPC - I want to know when the user has explicitly disconnected their wallet.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`accountschanged`](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html#accountschanged) event.

```
ethereum.on('accountsChanged', handler: (accounts: Array<string>) => void);
```

Answer (score 1):

Verify if has any account.

ex: the accounts variable return an array, if has any account on array your dapp is conneted.

Use this code bellow:

```
const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: "eth_accounts" });
const isConnected = !!accounts.length;
```